# What is the penalty for not closing an account in Netherlands?

Tags: netherlands, banking

I am an EU citizen. 11 months ago, I opened an account with ING bank in the Netherlands. I was working in the country and needed an account to receive my salary.

However, I never received a debit card. After some time, I have left the Netherlands. I have unregistered the address, but I did not close my account.

Today, I received a message that I should check my debit account with the ING app. I don't have an app; I can't even open it because I never used this account. I don't even know the account number.

Can you, please, explain to me what penalties I can expect to pay, and how can I contact ING to close an account? Also, is it possible that someone else could use this account to run up debts? That is my biggest concern. Also, how much, if anything, does ING charge for sending warnings? Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked the ING terms and conditions? Have you tried calling them (look up the contact number yourself, to be sure it’s the correct one). Even if you don’t know the account number the bank should be able to trace your account

Comment: Consider the possibility that you're receiving a scam text message from somebody else (not Ing) that references a "debt in your Ing app". This happens every day to people all around the world. Bottom line, call Ing (using contact info on their web page, don't reply to or use the text message) and find out.

Answer (score 2):

> Can you, please, explain me what penalties Can I expect to pay

No penalties AFAICT. ING [caters](https://www.ing.com/Newsroom/News/Press-releases/PROld/International-banking-with-ING.htm) to "international clients". But - you may be paying some account management fees, via a negative balance in your account.

> How Can I contact them to close an account?

Call their [customer service](https://www.ing.be/en/retail/contact) at +32 2 464 60 04 , and/or use their [contact page](https://www.ing.com/Contact-us.htm).